# every symmetric matrix can be orthogonality diagonalised

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_n (\mathbb R)$ be a symmetric matrix. It is known that $A$ is unitary diagonalizable. That means there exists some orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $$P^TAP=D$$where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Every proof that I saw for this theorem is based on the theory of inner product vector spaces. My question is: Is there any proof that do not use that theory? Is there a proof that $A$ is only diagonalizable (without orthogonality)?

Comment: In a sense, the definition of the transpose has its roots in an inner-product based theory, so it's not clear that such a proof would be useful.  In particular, what would an "orthogonal" matrix be if we don't have an inner product?

Comment: This is the reason that I used a matrix. you can define orthogonal matrix by $P^T=P^{-1}$

Comment: My question is also that we can prove that every real symmetric matrix is only diagonalizable? question was edited

Comment: Here's the fundamental question: what does $A^T$ mean in terms of $A$, if we don't use the inner product at any point?  What makes a matrix "symmetric" over a certain basis, but not over others?

Comment: Another way of saying this: as soon as you bring transposes into play, we have the inner product $\langle u,v \rangle = v^T u$